# How to print html output each on its line in python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so i'm making alittle project as i am a beginner and i'm doing some webscraping. I wanted to print the lyrics of a song each on it's line using beautifulsoup in python but instead it's printing like this:

I looked out this morning and the sun was goneTurned on some music to start my dayI lost myself in a familiar songI closed my eyes and I slipped awayIt's more than a feeling (more than a feeling)When I hear that old song they used to play (more than a feeling)And I begin dreaming (more than a feeling)Till I see Marianne walk awayI see my Marianne walkin' awaySo many people have come and goneTheir faces fade as the years go byYet I still recall as I wander onAs clear as the sun in the summer skyIt's more than a feeling (more than a feeling)When I hear that old song they used to play (more than a feeling)And I begin dreaming (more than a feeling)Till I see Marianne walk awayI see my Marianne walkin' awayWhen I'm tired and thinking coldI hide in my music, forget the dayAnd dream of a girl I used to knowI closed my eyes and she slipped awayShe slipped awayIt's more than a feeling (more than a feeling)When I hear that old song they used to play (more than a feeling)And I begin dreaming (more than a feeling)Till I see Marianne walk away

This is my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.urlopen("http://www.metrolyrics.com/more-than-a-feeling-lyrics-boston.html")

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

namelist = bsObj.find_all("div", {"id": "lyrics-body-text"})

print("".join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in namelist]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing it into a simple for loop

```
for p in namelist:
    print(p.get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: hello, it does the same :\

Comment: If you are using Python 3, try making the print statement into print(p.get_text(strip=True),end='\n'). Or try setting the strip parameter to False.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `strip = True` parameter to `get_text`. That strips the string resulting in the joined output you see.

By removing it:

```
print("".join([p.get_text() for p in namelist]))
```

It prints fine.

Comment: hello, i've tryed it before but it still prints like this

Comment: hello, strip False is doing the job :) so does your syntax, thanks alot :)